# Why does Mysql query get slow when I add a column to return?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, explain

I have a query that is running slowly (Both in Mysql 8 and MariaDB 10):

```
    select SQL_NO_CACHE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at)* 1000 AS x,
           value AS y, day(created_at), month(created_at), year(created_at) 
    from `portfolios` 
    where `user_id` = 3 and (created_at)>( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
    group by day(created_at),month(created_at), year(created_at) 
    order by `created_at` asc;
```

If I remove the 'value' column from the select, it runs fast.

The table is:

```
portfolios | CREATE TABLE `portfolios` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `value` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `portfolios_user_id_created_at_index` (`user_id`,`created_at`),
  KEY `portfolios_user_id_updated_at_index` (`user_id`,`updated_at`),
  KEY `portfolios_id_user_id_updated_at_index` (`id`,`user_id`,`updated_at`),
  KEY `portfolios_user_id_index` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11767164 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

the table has about **12 million** rows.

Running explain (without the 'value' column):

```
| id   | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys                                                                                    | key                                 | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                                     |
+------+-------------+------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | portfolios | range | portfolios_user_id_created_at_index,portfolios_user_id_updated_at_index,portfolios_user_id_index | portfolios_user_id_created_at_index | 9       | NULL | 183996 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
```

Running explain (with the 'value' column):

```
| id   | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys                                                                                    | key                                 | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                                  |
+------+-------------+------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | portfolios | range | portfolios_user_id_created_at_index,portfolios_user_id_updated_at_index,portfolios_user_id_index | portfolios_user_id_created_at_index | 9       | NULL | 184038 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort |
```

So when I add this column to the query it seems to stop 'using where, using index' and start 'using index condition'.

I don't really understand why simply adding a column to the select is causing this to slow down (15 seconds compared to about .3) - is it due to the size of the table?

I'd appreciate any advice on how to get this running faster!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: None of your indexes contain the value column so MySQL has to scan the table to fetch the value in order to generate complete result. Create an index such as `(user_id, created_at, value)` and see the improvement in performance.

Comment: Your query also produces incorrect results because the columns in group by do not match the columns in select.

Comment: I've changed the query to my actual one - I simplified for readability, but you're right re incorrect results.

Comment: The index worked! Thanks - I thought indexes were only really useful on columns used in Where etc, not in the select... my bad.
Please create an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: *I thought indexes were only really useful on columns used in Where etc, not in the select...* This is covering index - index which includes all columns used in the query. In this case all columns values are extracted from the index, and the table body not needed at all. Your performance degrade was caused by this need - after working with the index server accesses the table body for to extract `value` column values.

Comment: A clue:  "Using index" (in the Extra column of Explain) means "covering index".  "Using index condition" refers to something less significant.

Comment: Tip:  It is rarely useful to have a KEY (`id`,`user_id`,`updated_at`) that _starts_ with the column(s) of the `PRIMARY KEY`.  After all, the data is indexed by the PK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query involves three columns: `user_id`, `created_at` and `value`.

You have a few indexes on your table but none of them contains the `value` column. The explain seems to indicate that MySQL is using the `(user_id, updated_at)` index to filter matching rows but in order to generate the complete result it also scans the table to extract values from `value` column for matching rows.

If you create an index on `(user_id, created_at, value)` it could be used as a covering index... to match the where clause and and to lookup `value` from the index. MySQL no longer needs to touch the 22mil rows table.

---

Also, your `GROUP BY` is incorrect. I am guessing you need to count or sum the values for each day of year in which case you need to:

```sql
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST(created_at AS DATE)) * 1000, SUM(values)
FROM t
WHERE ...
GROUP BY CAST(created_at AS DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(created_at AS DATE)
```

Comment: It does not "scan" the table to get `value`; it "reaches into".